# Is it legal to distribute ipa files signed with developer account to a third party for testing purpose?

Tags: developer-program

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a Xcode project and I have archived and produced an ipa for the development deployment.
2. This ipa file can obviosly only be installed on my device.
3. Now, I give this ipa to a third party MDM provider.
4. Third party enroll my device into their MDM, upload the ipa on their MDM and pushes the app to my device.
5. This way I can run that app on my device.

Is this allowed in the licensed granted by Apple to Xcode users? I am specifically concerned over the part where I have to email the ipa to the third party MDM provider.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53177/discussion-on-question-by-nitinsh99-is-it-legal-to-distribute-ipa-files-signed-w).

Comment: I'l tempted to edit this, but there are really two missing pieces for it to be answerable - 1) are you only bound by Xcode EULA or also a developer agreement. (If you have signed a specific contract with Apple to get a signing certigficate you need to speficy that explicitly in the body) 2) Are you use ad-hoc signing or a paid signing certificate? Keep in mind **We are not lawyers and certainly not _your_ lawyers** - once we've pointed you to the EULA - you need to take that to your lawyer for a ruling on legality as opposed to licensed use.